# Meu front-end não está se comunicando com o Back-End

Tags: react

Criei um form simples no React para se comunicar com o back-end(Node js), mas quando click no botão do form(este botão tem um evento que é responsável por realizar a solicitação ao back-end dá a seguinte mensagem:  "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

```js
onClick = (event) => {
  httRequest.open('GET', 'https://localhost:5000', true);

  httRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ( httRequest.readyState === 4 ){
      if ( httRequest.status === 200 ) 
        console.log(httRequest.responseText)
      else
        console.log('Some error in httRequest.readyState == 200')
    } else
      console.log('Error in the if == 4')
  }
  httRequest.send();
}
```

Basicamente, quando chamado o evento, ele deveria fazer a solicitação o endereço citado.
Mas sempre que seleciono o botão ele cai na condição abaixo:

```
console.log('Some error in httRequest.readyState == 200')
```

Comment: Alberto, você está utilizando https local?

Comment: Não, estou usando http, mas acho que já resolvi o problema. Tenho que usar o CORS na outra aplicação junto ao express.

Comment: Funcionou, agora tenho que mandar as informações do Form (front-end) para a segunda aplicação (back-end) criar no banco de dados.

Comment: Você provavelmente vai ter problemas no localhost para fazer isso, quando usa protocolo https, até porque na máquina local você precisa liberar o acesso ao endereço local no link do seu navegador, faça isso primeiro antes de fazer uma chamada de requisição...